# Is there a way to minimise a function and maximise another at the same time?

Tags: optimization

Say I have two functions of the variable x, f and g. I would like to find a single value of x that gives me the largest value of f and smallest value of g. Is there a procedure to do this? Note: I'm not talking about the global maximum of f and global minimum of g, just some large value of f and some small value of g.

Can this be generalised to an arbitrary number of functions? E.g. I want to find the value of x such that I get the largest values possible of functions f and g, and smallest values possible of functions p, q, and r.

Also, I am not sure what to tag this post as aside from optimization.

Edit: So I might have just asked an XY problem. So here is the initial problem. There are two functions of "w", risk(w) and reward(w). Essentially I want to minimise risk while maximising the reward.

Comment: In general, this can't be done. What are you trying to do that makes you ask this question? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: In general, you have to decide what you are trying to maximize.  Plausible choices might be $f(x) - g(x)$ or $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.  For the latter choice, you would have to decide how to interpret (for example) $g(x) = 0$ and (perhaps separately) $g(x) < 0.$

Comment: How would you differentiate two max-min pars? Say you have by some procedure  these (1,4), (2,5), (0,3)... which one would you pick? In any case when you decide how to differentiate these, say |f(x)-g(x)|, then it is the matter of finding the max for that expression and job done.

Comment: @TobyMak I'm reading about modern portfolio theory. We have two functions of the variable "w", risk(w) and return(w). The goal is to pick a w such that risk is minimised and return is maximised.

Comment: @user2661923 So I guess choosing a ratio or difference is up to the specific real-life application.

Comment: In that case, it would make sense to calculate expected return.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [Goal Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goal_programming).

Comment: Maximize the function $f-g$.

Comment: @awkward Would it be that simple though? Like thinking from a real-life perspective, return has units say dollars, but risk doesn't have units of dollars, so a simple subtraction doesn't make physical sense.

Comment: I would not say that goal programming is simple, but it can handle multipole objectives with different units of measurement.  It's up to you to define the trade-offs between the objectives.